# Path transparent only on macOS

Tags: swift, swiftui

Why are paths slightly transparent on macOS and not iOS? How can I make them not transparent on macOS?

Minimal reproducible example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 300))
            }
            .stroke(lineWidth: 8)
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 200))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 450))
            }
            .stroke(lineWidth: 8)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. All the code needed should be in the Question, I want to emphasize minimal example we don't need the whole project.

Comment: I have updated the post, thank you.